# WPF ListView : Bind column Width of two ListView to each other?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview

In my WPF application I have two ListView with identical columns. I want to bind the column width of the ListViews to each other. When I resize a column in one ListView I want the matching column in the other ListView to have the same width.

It would be great if there would be no "Master"-ListView. Each ListView should update the other one.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

The section "How to share the width of a column over multiple grids" should answer your question.

Comment: The OP is asking about `ListView` (data) columns, not `Grid` (layout) columns.